# Creating Sharepoint Web Part manifest file and dwp files

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

Could anyone please help me to understand the following for creating Sharepoint web part please?

1. Manifest.xml
   a. What is the purpose of this file?

   b. What happens if we specify the wrong *.wpd file as below?

   ```
    <DwpFiles>
   <DwpFile FileName="WebPart1.dwp"/>
   ```

   c. How do I create file in Visual Studio as I can't see any template
2. *.wpd

   1. What is the purpose of this file?
   2. How does this loads the proper dll?
   3. How do we create using Visual studio, any template exists?
3. If we have webpart project and it references to the dll on another project. Does another project's dll has to be signed?
4. What are the best mechanisms to deploy the Sharepoint Web Parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [WspBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/) Visual Studio templates. They are a little quirky but it makes creating the structure of SharePoint projects very simple.

It uses the convention of following the SharePoint folder layout for specifying file locations in the project. Take a look - it might help you get moving. Note there are two versions - one for [Visual Studio 2008](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/30858/download/77208) and a beta for [Visual Studio 2010](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/releases/30858/download/94507).

To try to answer your specific questions:

1. If the file can't be found, no action is taken. It's an error but not one that will bring down SharePoint.
2. I thought WPD was the old package style. Maybe I'm wrong on this?

   1. Should be same as WSP - a package containing files to be deployed.
   2. Whatever DLL is contained in the package is deployed to the GAC if it's signed.
   3. Take a look at previously mentioned WSP Builder project.
3. Anything that's loaded by SharePoint and leads to rendered content needs to be signed and possibly added to the SafeControls entry in the web.config (deploying WSPs created from WSPBuilder does this automatically)
4. "stsadm -o addsolution" then use Central Admin to deploy or continue with "stsadm -o deploysolution"